# Total up value in database column and display in chart ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to sum up the value of the quantity column for my chart.

```
var db = Database.Open("OrdersContext");
var data = db.Query("SELECT ProductId,Quantity  FROM OrderDetails");
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Green)


   .AddTitle("Product Sales")
   .AddSeries("Default",
xValue: data, xField: "ProductId",
yValues: data, yFields:"Quantity")
    .Write();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
var db = Database.Open("OrdersContext");
var data = db.Query("SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) TotalQuantity FROM OrderDetails Group By ProductId");
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Green)


   .AddTitle("Product Sales")
   .AddSeries("Default",
xValue: data, xField: "ProductId",
yValues: data, yFields:"TotalQuantity")
    .Write();
```

This query will give you sum of each product quantity